# move to mvc from existing asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have used .net framework 4.0 to design my web project I want to improve some features on my web site and I decided to use MVC in my project.

I research about mvc I found out System.Web.Routing in .net framework 3.5 is wrapped by System.Web in .net framework 4.0.

In the other side in my host environment I have IIS 7.0 with all necessarily handlers mapped to .aspx and some other extension like .cshtml and support them.

So I think I have all thing for mvc migration. my question is :

Is it possible to move mvc by configure web.config and make some structure for content, view and controller classes but don't change any asp.net pages and configuration like appcode and appdata which I had before in my asp.net application.

Note, I don't want to change or update my old application to mvc I want to add some mvc controllers class and view to my existing asp.net project to use mvc functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this walkthrough from Scott Hanselman:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx